# NPM peer requirements error

Tags: angularjs, meteor, npm, requirements, peer

Apologies if this is a dumb question - I'm a complete Meteor Noob...

I'm building an app using meteor 1.3.1 and the Socially tutorial as a reference as it does something very similar to what I need, but I keep seeing the same error in my console and just can't figure it out.

I've installed the accounts.ui package:

```
meteor add dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
```

then added that package as a dependency in my angular module:

```
angular.module('dkfitness', [
'angular-meteor',
'ui.router',
'angularMoment',
'accounts.ui'
]);
```

I have angular installed, .meteor/versions lists:

> angular@1.3.9_2

but I keep seeing the following error:

`check-npm-versions.js:17 Error: Cannot find module
'angular/package.json'(…) check-npm-versions.js:48 WARNING: npm peer
requirements not installed:- angular@^1.2.27 not installed.`

I've tried to force the package version of angular to 1.2.27 
I've also run:

```
meteor npm install --save angular
```

Neither fixes the issue.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue?

Comment: No not yet - need to try the angular 1.3.1 install but not in a place I can test for two more days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the offending line of code has been removed from the dotansimha:dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular

But there was no jump in the release number. Its still 0.0.4

Anyhow to fix this issue just remove and add the package. 
meteor remove dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
meteor add dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular

@alexbouchardd: Thanks for spotting this issue.

Update: The problem is also due to this portion in accounts-ui-angular.js

- try {
- if (Package['modules-runtime']) {
- var require = Package['modules-runtime'].meteorInstall();
- require('angular');
- }
- } catch(e) {
- throw new Error('angular package is missing');
- }

Reverted the codes here to the earlier version

- if (!window.angular) {
- require("angular");
- }

Followed alexbouchardd's steps to clone and replace dotansimha:dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular

Comment: Thanks! I tried removing the package and reinstalling it but am still getting that npm error. I'm wondering if the package may be cached somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

This is by no means a fix but rather a temporary workaround.

This issue is caused by npm version check for the package dependancy.

```
import {checkNpmVersions} from 'meteor/tmeasday:check-npm-versions';

if (!window.angular) {
  require("angular");
}

checkNpmVersions({
  'angular': '^1.2.27'
});
```

Workaround:

1. In your app directory create a new "packages" folder and clone the package directory from github (requires Git..)

   ```
   mkdir packages
   cd packages
   git clone https://github.com/dotansimha/accounts-ui-angular.git
   ```
2. In the file packages.js change

   ```
   -- name: "dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular",
   ++ name: "dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular-moded",
   ```
3. In file accounts-ui-angular.js change the following to remove the lines that version check

   ```
   -- import {checkNpmVersions} from 'meteor/tmeasday:check-npm-versions';

   if (!window.angular) {
     require("angular");
   }

   -- checkNpmVersions({
     -- 'angular': '^1.2.27'
   -- });
   ```
4. Then back to your app root, uninstall the original package and install the one we just modified.

   ```
   meteor remove dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular
   meteor add dotansimha:accounts-ui-angular-moded
   ```

Heads up, I am very new to this (first stackoverflow post, woot). I have no clue why this issue is occuring but it's the only solution I have found for the moment. Hope this helps and hopefully the official package / meteor will receive a fix soon!

Make sure you have angular above 1.2.27 installed since we are no longer verifying it.

```
meteor list
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, Did you have any conflicts with 2 separate versions of angular installed?

Comment: No I did verify, everything looked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to install angular 1.3.1. It is solved after i installed that version.

Comment: Angular 1.3.1 breaks my pagination :-(